# rails API using refile not filling in filename when uploading file from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have rails app that I am using for an API, so I can upload a file from a mobile application to the remote server via the API.  I am using the `refile` gem to manage the attachments in the rails app, and when I use `curl` to upload a file the `csv_file_filename` is filled in with the appropriate filename, however when I upload the file with iOS using AFNetworking I get a `null` value for `csv_file_filename`.

I am not sure what the difference between the curl command and AFNetworking is, but any suggestions would be greatly welcome.

The Objective-C code looks like the following,

```
- (void)exportUsers {
    NSLog(@"exportUsers method reached");

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *objectsForExport = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSArray *exportKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"pin", @"credit", @"email", @"lastLogin", @"rfid", @"phoneNumber", nil];

    NSMutableArray *csvObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objectsForExport count]];
    for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsForExport) {
        NSMutableArray *anObjectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[exportKeys count]];
        for (NSString *key in exportKeys) {
            id value = [object valueForKey:key];
            if (!value) {
                value = @"";
            }
            [anObjectArray addObject:[value description]];
        }
        [csvObjects addObject:anObjectArray];
    }
    NSLog(@"The output:%@",csvObjects);

    // need to figure out how to fetch the DeviceID and append it to the file name
    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    // write array to CSV file
    CHCSVWriter *csvWriter=[[CHCSVWriter alloc]initForWritingToCSVFile:[documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv]]];
    [csvWriter writeLineOfFields:csvObjects];

    [csvWriter closeStream];

    [self uploadCSV];
}

- (void) uploadCSV {
    NSLog(@"inside uploadCSV method");

    // begin uploading CSV file using AFNetworking
    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv]];

    NSLog(@"the filename is: %@",filename);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kegcop.chrisrjones.com/api/"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"csv_files" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv] mimeType:@"text/csv"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being my lack of knowledge knowing how AFNetworking works, ...surprise surprise.

I added an `NSDictionary` which contains the params for AFNetworking as opposed to leaving them `nil`.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"csv_file_filename":justFilename};
```

Then I added the `params` to the AFNetworking request,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"csv_files" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv] mimeType:@"text/csv"];
    }];
```

Also, I figured out how to truncate a path from a string var, so that way the entire path to file doesn't get uploaded to the `csv_file_filename` column in the DB.

The below snippet creates a string var with just the filename, which is what I was looking to achieve.

```
// the below string will include the entire path, not just the file name
    NSString *filename = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv]];

    // place just the filename in a string var
    NSString *justFilename = [filename lastPathComponent];
```